# What does the @ symbol mean in a react import statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a ruby on rails application with a react js frontend.

What does the @ signify here

```
import ProductCard from '@components/search/ProductCard';
```

Comment: It's either a webpack alias you have set up to map `@components` to a local folder so you don't have to do relative imports, or it's an npm scope: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope but scope seems less likely if it's named "components"

Comment: i get familiar with it in babel 7, it is called scoped packages  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#scoped-packages

Answer (score 51):

### Path mappings are aliases that point to specific folders

If you are using Typescript (which the tag suggests you are) it's possible to setup "path mapping" in your tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components": ["./src/components"]
    }
  }
}
```

This will create an alias for "@components" that points to a specific folder.

Read more about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

### Other possibilities

It could be a scoped package like `@types/xxx` but this is unlikely in the given case.

Answer (score -1):

**Module Aliasing or Path Mapping:**

Module aliasing, also known as path mapping, is a feature that allows developers to create custom shortcuts, or aliases, for module import paths. This feature enhances the convenience and readability of referencing modules within a project.

**For TypeScript (tsconfig.json) or JavaScript (jsconfig.json):**

To enhance the organization of your project and simplify import statements, you can configure module aliasing in your `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json` file in the root folder of your project. Whether you're using TypeScript or JavaScript, the process is quite similar.

**Example JSON Configuration File:**

```json
// tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json (choose based on your project)
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components": ["./src/components"]
    }
  }
}
```

In this example:

- `"baseUrl": "."` sets the base directory for module resolution.
- `"paths"` specify various aliases:

  - `"@": ["./src"]` maps the `@` alias to the `src` directory.
  - `"@/*": ["./src/*"]` allows you to use `@/` followed by any path within the `src` directory.
  - `"@components": ["./src/components"]` provides a specific alias for the `components` directory.

Feel free to customize these aliases based on your project structure. After adding this configuration, your import statements will become more concise, improving code readability.

Remember to restart your development server or rebuild your project after making changes to the configuration file. If you have any questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask!