# I'm setting up jest in my react project that build with vite and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, ts-jest

I can't figure out the relative path of the file i imported in App.test.tsx is wrong or something
it's keep telling me that
`Cannot find module '@/components/items/card.tsx' from 'src/__tests__/App.test.tsx'`

Here is my code

```
// eslint-disable
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Card from "@/components/items/card.tsx";
import lineUpCardBack from "@/assets/images/backOfLineUpCard.jpg";
import lurking from "@/assets/images/lineUp/lurking.jpg";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import App from "../App";


const CardMockProps = {
  cardFrontUrl:lurking,
  cardBackUrl:lineUpCardBack,
  cardState:"open",
  cardCoordinate: { currentCoordinateX: 10, currentCoordinateY: 20 },
  canBeTurn:true 
}


test("test1", async () => {
  render(<Card {...CardMockProps}/>);
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});

test("test2",async () => {
  render(<App/>);

  const titleElement = screen.getByText("風聲");
  expect(titleElement).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

and below is my repo
https://github.com/yi-luan/The-Message

i have been trying to modify my jest.config.ts,but it still not working...

```
export default {
    rootDir: ".",
    roots: ["./src"],
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
      "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg)$": "<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    }
};
```

Comment: I assume that there is a problem with the "@" sign. When does this error occur(build, test)? Looking at your package.json you are using tsc to compile your code. That means, that the "@" sign is used as a path mapping according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306700/18004317). Then you have to configure them in your tsconfig. I did not use Jest before, so I might be wrong, but I think that Jest is not the source for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this issue before recently too. It looks like you're missing a mapping for your module path in `moduleNameMapper`.

In your case, firstly ensure your aliases are in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      //other compiler options...

      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
         "@/*": ["src/*"]
      }
   }
}
```

Then you'll have to add the following expression to map your path in your `moduleNameMapper` in `jest.config.ts`:

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
      //other mappings...
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
    }
```

This regular expression should find any module path beginning with `@/` and map it to a path jest can use.